# Override CSS of component selector style from ng module

Tags: css, .net, angular, angular7

I'm trying to modify the css color picker of a module, in order to adapt it to my website (align it to center).

Here's the code of the color picker:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'color-circle',
  template: `
    <div
      class="circle-picker {{ className }}"
      [style.width.px]="width"
      [style.margin-right.px]="-circleSpacing"
      [style.margin-bottom.px]="-circleSpacing"
    >
      <color-circle-swatch
        *ngFor="let color of colors"
        [circleSize]="circleSize"
        [circleSpacing]="circleSpacing"
        [color]="color"
        [focus]="isActive(color)"
        (onClick)="handleBlockChange($event)"
        (onSwatchHover)="onSwatchHover.emit($event)"
      ></color-circle-swatch>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      .circle-picker {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
      }
    `,
  ],
```

I'm using `justify-content: center` to the class circle-picker to align it, but nothing happens, so I don't really know if I'm able to do it.

Here's how I use the selector:

```
<color-circle [colors]="colors" [color]="productForm.get('color')?.value" (onChange)="onColorChanged($event)" width="190px" circleSize="34" circleSpacing="18"></color-circle>
```

When I inspect the code with the browser, I can make it, but with the CSS file nothing works.

Could anyone help?

This is what I want:

[image]

This is what I have:

[image]

Author of the color picker:
https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-color

Comment: try use `margin-right:auto` and `margin-left:auto` to `color-circle-swatch`

Comment: or use `justify-content: center` to child not to parent (in your case `.circle-picker` is parent)

Comment: None of them work.

Comment: do you want the `color-circle-swatch` be in center of `circle-picker`

Comment: can you check the question? I've uploaded some pictures.

Comment: You can override, but you have to do it at global styles css, not just at a component style. It is working already.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set style to elements inside your `host` component. you must use `:host`
and to change deeper  elements you have to use [`::ng-deep`](https://ngrefs.com/en/latest/styling/ng-deep-selector)

Use

```
:host color-circle ::ng-deep color-circle-swatch{
   justify-content: center;
   align-items:center
}
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: please add your code to https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master fork and post link

Comment: also look at F12 to see what happend

Answer (score 1):

May be this two line of code can fix your problem

```
.color-circle-swatch{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I cannot access to that class directly I think

Comment: where do you set your css(I mean in which component) ??